# Event Email receipt doesn't have the profile information

Tags: civievent, paypal, receipts

I have an event which accepts multiple participants registration, I have used a profile and another different profile for the additional participants and I have checked the "Same Email address" checkbox.

The issue is that on registering multiple participants only the first participant's profile field's information is present in the Email receipt and other participant's information is not present. Total Amount is also empty.

This issue is happening on using "PayPal - Website Payments Standard" processor but all the participant's information is coming correctly upon using the "Pay Later" option. 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: We've just come across this problem too, which affects event receipts from any 'external' payment processors. We're looking into it and will post an update when we have more information and (hopefully) a fix!

Comment: I've raised a CiviCRM core issue for this [= https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4069